# How to generate a pop-up window if column contains string in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

The following code results in a browser opening and displaying several columns. One of the column "**Checked"** can display TRUE or FALSE. I would like to have something like the "Checked = file.exists(File))", and if TRUE do nothing, and if FALSE then open a popup window with message "file(s) do not exist".

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(openxlsx)

r=sort(list.dirs(path = '/ESS_mounts/atoto/data/demultiplex/', full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE), decreasing = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("toto Report"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('RunID','Choose an toto RunID:', r),
    selectInput('StudyID','Choose StudyID:', NULL),
    downloadButton("download", "Download .xlsx"),
    width=3
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('data'),
    width=9
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  study <- reactive({
    s=read.csv(paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',input$RunID,'/SampleSheet.csv'), skip=suppressWarnings(grep('[Data]',readLines(paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',input$RunID,'/SampleSheet.csv')), fixed=TRUE)))
    m=s %>%
      pull(Sample_Project) %>%
      unique()
    m
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = 'StudyID', choices = study())
  })

  data <- reactive({
    j=fromJSON(paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',input$RunID,'/Stats/Stats.json'))
    s=read.csv(paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',input$RunID,'/SampleSheet.csv'), colClasses=c('Sample_Name'='character'), skip=suppressWarnings(grep('[Data]',readLines(paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',input$RunID,'/SampleSheet.csv')), fixed=TRUE)))
    t=j$ConversionResults$DemuxResults %>%
      bind_rows(.id = 'Lane') %>%
      rename(TotalYield = Yield,) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(IndexMetrics, ReadMetrics)) %>%
      rename(Read=ReadNumber) %>%
      mutate(Q30 = 100*YieldQ30/Yield) %>%
      select(SampleName,Lane,Read,NumberReads,Yield,Q30)
    m=s %>%
      mutate(index2 = ifelse("index2" %in% names(.), index2, NA), SampleSheetRow = row_number(), Instrument = str_split(j$RunId,'_')[[1]][2], Side = substr(str_split(j$RunId,'_')[[1]][4],1,1), RunNumber = str_pad(j$RunNumber, width=4, pad=0), RunID = j$RunId, Flowcell = j$Flowcell) %>%
      rename(Index1 = index, Index2 = index2, LibraryName = Description, StudyID = Sample_Project, SampleName = Sample_Name) %>%
      select(StudyID,SampleName,LibraryName,Index1,Index2,Instrument,Side,RunNumber,RunID,Flowcell,SampleSheetRow) %>%
      right_join(t, by = 'SampleName') %>%
      mutate(File = paste0('/Server/data/demultiplex/',RunID,'/',StudyID,'/',LibraryName,'/',LibraryName,'_',Instrument,'_',RunNumber,'_',SampleName,'_S',SampleSheetRow,'_L00',Lane,'_R',Read,'_001.fastq.gz'), Checked = file.exists(File)) %>%
      filter(StudyID == input$StudyID ) %>%
      mutate(SampleName = str_replace(SampleName,'_' ,'-'))
    m
  })

  output$data <- renderTable({
    data()
  }, rownames = TRUE)

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(input$StudyID, '_', input$RunID, '.xlsx')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.xlsx(data(), file, colNames = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to include an `if()` but this doesn't work and reports errors.